# Flutter Database retrieving data and show it on another screen

Tags: database, flutter

Hi I'm working on a flutter project

Here's my **DB file**

**notes_service.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:my_notebook/extensions/list/filter.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:my_notebook/services/crud/crud_exceptions.dart';

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  List<DatabaseNotes> _notes = [];

  DatabaseUser? _user;

  static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
  NotesService._sharedInstance() {
    _notesStreamController = StreamController<List<DatabaseNotes>>.broadcast(
      onListen: () {
        _notesStreamController.sink.add(_notes);
      },
    );
  }
  factory NotesService() => _shared;

  late final StreamController<List<DatabaseNotes>> _notesStreamController;

  Stream<List<DatabaseNotes>> get allNotes =>
      _notesStreamController.stream.filter((note) {
        final currentUser = _user;
        if (currentUser != null) {
          return note.userId == currentUser.id;
        } else {
          throw UserShouldBeSetBeforeReadingAllNotesException();
        }
      });

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({
    required String email,
    bool setAsCurrentUser = true,
  }) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      if (setAsCurrentUser) {
        _user = user;
      }
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUserException {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      if (setAsCurrentUser) {
        _user = createdUser;
      }
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNotes note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure note exists
    await getNotes(id: note.id);

    // update db
    final updateCount = await db.update(
      notesTable,
      {
        textColumn: text,
        isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 0,
      },
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [note.id],
    );

    if (updateCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNoteException();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNotes(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNotes>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final notes = await db.query(notesTable);

    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNotes.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> getNotes({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final notes = await db.query(
      notesTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNoteException();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNotes.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notes.add(note);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final numOfDeletions = await db.delete(notesTable);
    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    return numOfDeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      notesTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNoteException();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);

    // making sure owner exists in db with correct id
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUserException();
    }

    const text = '';

    // create note
    final noteId = await db.insert(
      notesTable,
      {
        userIdColumn: owner.id,
        textColumn: text,
        isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 1,
      },
    );

    final note = DatabaseNotes(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUserException();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExistsException();
    }

    final userId = await db.insert(
      userTable,
      {
        emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
      },
    );

    return DatabaseUser(
      id: userId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUserException();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenedException();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseNotOpenedException();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    try {
      await open();
    } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenedException {}
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenedException();
    }
    try {
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;

      // create user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);

      // create note table
      await db.execute(createNotesTable);

      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentDirectoryException();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;

  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });

  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email = $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNotes {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

  DatabaseNotes({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });

  DatabaseNotes.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud =
            (map[isSyncedWithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, text = $text, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNotes other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'notes.db';
const userTable = 'user';
const notesTable = 'notes';
const idColumn = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const textColumn = 'text';
const isSyncedWithCloudColumn = 'is_synced_with_cloud';
const createUserTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
  "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "email"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);''';
const createNotesTable = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "notes" (
  "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "text"    TEXT,
  "is_synced_with_cloud"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id"),
  PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);''';
```

And now I want to get the email address when user is filling the form (TextFieldController) for registering.
So how can I get the email address and show it on another screen?
And if I added some extra fields on register form (eg: Name, Address etc) do I need to update on above sql?
I'm actually new to databases. I'm willing to have your help.